# which data is returned by Highgui.imWrite()

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

it might be an easy question but i checked [this docs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite) and it is not clear which kind of data type is returned by the method

`HighGui.imWrite()`

there is no explanation about the returned value, can any one help

Comment: it's a boolean value, signifying if the operation worked (ot not)

Comment: @berak yes i expected that as well but is that written in the docs? i think you just inferred that as you have experience in programming. thank you

Comment: what, if you actually [look at the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/highgui/Highgui.html#imwrite(java.lang.String,%20org.opencv.core.Mat))  (for a change..)